# C _Generic error - expected expression before '_Bool'

Tags: c, generic-programming

I am learning about C _Generic.
Here's the question:
Why I cannot compile the code below successfully?
It will only issue the error as the title.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define EVALUATE(X) _Generic((X), _Bool : "boolean", default : "not boolean")

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", EVALUATE(5));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks OK to me and compiles. Which compiler do you use (which version, which options)?

Comment: Oh, and please confirm you don't get an "implicit declaration of `_Generic`" warning but didn't bother to post it...

Comment: Gcc compiler using CodeBlock IDE and compilation version is c11

Comment: Hm. What's the output of `gcc --version`?

Comment: My 4.7.2 (Debian) has only incomplete C11 support, and no `_Generic` at all. So I guess that's your answer: Get a newer Gcc. But then again, you should get a warning for the implicit declaration of `_Generic` (Gcc assumes a function `extern int _Generic();` in that case, and trying to parse the generic expression as a function call, of course, leads to a syntax error).

Comment: Well I will try it
anyway, thanks for your helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Generic` is not supported in gcc [until 4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status). `_Bool` is supported in your current compiler, but since the compiler thinks that `_Generic` is a regular implicit function, it pushes out a warning about the odd parameter.

#### GCC 4.7.1

```
[9:25am][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.7.1/bin/gcc -std=c11 foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_Generic’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
foo.c:7:20: error: expected expression before ‘_Bool’
```

#### GCC 4.8.2

```
[9:26am][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gcc -std=c11 foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_Generic’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%s\n", EVALUATE(5));
     ^
foo.c:3:35: error: expected expression before ‘_Bool’
 #define EVALUATE(X) _Generic((X), _Bool : "boolean", default : "not boolean")
                                   ^
foo.c:7:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘EVALUATE’
     printf("%s\n", EVALUATE(5));
                    ^
```

#### GCC 4.9.0

```
[9:26am][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.9.0/bin/gcc -std=c11 foo.c
[9:27am][wlynch@apple /tmp] ./a.out 
not boolean
```

Comment: Yeah you are right.
After I updated the compiler the problem had just gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your compiler does not support type `_Bool`. You can check this by declaring a variable of type `_Bool`. For example

```
_Bool b = 1;

printf( "%d\n", b );
```

As for the generic then replace `_Bool` with `int`.

If after such a replacement the code will not be compiled then it means that the compiler does not support generic.:)

Comment: It does support it
It is same with changing the _Bool type into double

Comment: @AhSeng Fan You may not initialize type double with a character literal.

Comment: Problem solved after updated the gcc version.
before that my gcc compiler is ver 4.7.2 and now the version is 4.9.2
Anyway, thanks for helping :)